Dropping definite articles when connecting sentences through usage of laut

Aufgabe: Verbinden Sie die Sätze mit den angegebenen Konnektoren
Q: Die nasse Deposition von Plastik ist allgegenwärtig. Das sagen die Forscher
Ans: Laut Forschern ist die nasse Deposition von Plastik allgegenwärtig

In the answer above, why did we drop the definite articles when we reformulated the sentence?

This is a mistake in the answer key. Either it's

Das sagen die Forscher. — Laut den Forschern …

or

Das sagen Forscher. — Laut Forschern …

The variant with the definite article points out that it's definite Forscher we talk about. People who have been introduced earlier. That's what definiteness means. So you have to retain that property in the answer.

There is a subtle shift of meaning between question and this answer. "Das sagen die Forscher" with the artikel means "this is what the researchers / research shows", and without the article "das sagen Forscher" it means "some researchers say". The difference is that either the entire community of the researchers agrees (die Forscher) or that some of them say it (others may disagree, or we have not tried to ask many of them). To align these two meanings, the "den" should be added in the answer.
